# Android: How to Create a Modal Progress "Wheel" Overlay?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I would like to show a modal progress "wheel" overlay on my view.

The ProgressDialog comes close, but I do not want the dialog background or border.

I tried setting the background drawable of the dialog window:

```
this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);

this.progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
this.progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

this.progressDialog.show();
```

but to no avail (i.e. still looks the same as without the ...setBackgroundDrawable code).

Comment: Should maybe repick the right answer seems the one picked is jsut a pointer to the tutorial, the one everyone is up voting has a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)? At the end of the page it talks about how to create a custom dialog, and that might help you put a spinner progress dialog box with your own backgrounds.

Comment: For those wondering why this answer has few upvotes, probably this: "Caution: Android includes another dialog class called ProgressDialogthat shows a dialog with a progress bar. This widget is deprecated because it prevents users from interacting with the app while progress is being displayed." You should use the next answer and include it in your layout.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if there is a better way, but you could get the spinner wheel on its own by using a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) and setting it to be interdeterminate. If you are using an [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) you can put it over other views. This layout should demonstrate this method with XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true" android:layout_x="100dip"
        android:layout_y="10dip" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"></ProgressBar>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_y="25dip" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm sure this would work as well, so i've voted up, but i went for the other solution as it was simpler to implement.

Comment: Just for everybody new to this question. AbsoluteLayout is deprecated since API Level 3. What ever that means to you guys.

Comment: Since AbsoluteLayout is depricated, use a FrameLayout to position things on top of each other like in EZDsIt's answer.

Answer (score 11):

In order to create a full screen progress on a darkened background I use a FrameLayout and set the visibility of the RelativeLayout to VISIBLE when required or GONE when the long operation is done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dip" >

            <!-- Your regular UI here -->

    </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/relativelayout_progress"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:visibility="gone"
       android:background="#aa000022" >

       <ProgressBar 
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:indeterminateOnly="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I really like the idea of this one, pretty easy to implement. I just recommend adding an `OnTouchEventListener` to the RelativeLayout that returns true, so that your touch events won't be passed through to the underlying FrameLayout.

Comment: another solution is to make FrameLayout `android:clickable="true"`

Answer (score 3):

Klarth's solution worked for me, thanks!

In my case I used the layout_gravity for center placement of the progress_indicator, rather than using explicit coordinates.

```
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/pb"
        android:layout_width="40dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:indeterminate="true" 
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

you just add `.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` to your ProgressDialog.

```
 ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
 dialog.setMessage("your message...");
 dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
 dialog.show();
```

Comment: This is deprecated